# Firebase In-app messaging send message whenever we need option?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-in-app-messaging

I have successfully implemented firebase In-app messaging, working fine. Is there any option to send In-app message whenever we want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase in-app messages are automatically triggered based on rules you write when you build the app.

If you want to show a message in an app at a moment you determine after the app has shipped, you should use Firebase Cloud Messaging for delivering those messages, or at least to trigger their display.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android#send_a_test_message):

> To conserve power, Firebase In-App Messaging only retrieves messages from the server once per day. That can make testing difficult, so the Firebase console allows you to specify a test device that displays messages on demand.