# Hpw to do In app notification from Backend

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-in-app-messaging

Is it possible to send in-app notification from spring boot app?

Based on the docs and sdk firebase-admin I could send push notifications. But for in app messaging I am not sure that will help send notifications from backend server

Comment: yes you can, check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72471308/2165146

Answer (score 1):

In-app messaging, as its name implies, is for messages that are triggered from (and displayed) inside the app. When the user is not actively using the app, you'll usually instead want to send a notification to Cloud Messaging, with shows up in the notification panel.

There is no direct way to trigger In-app messaging from your own server, but since the triggers are based on Analytics events - you could send a message from your server to the device (for example as a *data* message through FCM) and then use that in the app as a signal to log a certain analytics event that then triggers In-app messaging.

Also see:

- [Firebase In-app messaging send message whenever we need option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885009/firebase-in-app-messaging-send-message-whenever-we-need-option)
- [How to send In-APP Notification in Firebase using Python SDK for Android | iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222448/how-to-send-in-app-notification-in-firebase-using-python-sdk-for-android-ios)